# How to store current user data securely with using angular 5?

Tags: angular, userid

I have project in laravel(backend) and angular (frontend) . I need to know how can i store user data securely in local server (client side). what is best and reliable method to use. any plugin in angular or else. and how can we fetch user id of current user in angular..

thank you

Comment: What kind of data will be stored, and what will it be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **angular-web-storage**.

[angular-web-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-web-storage)

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-storage-pwip2c)

**Angular decorator to save and restore of HTML5 Local&Session Storage**

**Installation:**

```
npm install angular-web-storage --save
```

Import the `AngularWebStorageModule` in your module.

```
import { AngularWebStorageModule } from 'angular-web-storage';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        AngularWebStorageModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data isn't sensitive, you could use laravel to encrypt it and store it inside a cookie in the client's browser.